# How to hide form in modal in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a modal containing two forms, I want to switch between them when one of the radio buttons is checked, so i need to hide one of them in modal load, i did the following code, but it doesn't hide, can anyone help me in that?
The Form need to be hidden on modal load is called `LocateOnMap` to hide all its content.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal-Frm">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-sm" style="width:480px;">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h3 class="modal-title">Add New Farmer</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <form action="AddNewCustomer.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <label class="Modallabel">Address:</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="optradio">Enter Address</label>
                        <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="optradio">Locate on Map</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <form id="LocateOnMap">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <label class="Modallabel"></label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                            <div class="input-group input-group-sm" style="margin-top: -5px;margin-left: -15px;">
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <label class="Modallabel">Latitude:</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-8">
                                    <div class="input-group input-group-sm" style="margin-top: -5px;">
                                        <input id="Latitude" type="text" class="form-control ModalInput" name="Latitude" placeholder="Latitude" style="border-radius: 5px;" readonly >
                                    </div><br>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <label class="Modallabel">Longitude:</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-8">
                                    <div class="input-group input-group-sm" style="margin-top: -5px;">
                                        <input id="Longitude" type="text" class="form-control ModalInput" name="Longitude" placeholder="Longitude" style="border-radius: 5px;" readonly >
                                    </div>
                                </div> 
                            </div><br>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row" style="padding: 10px;">
                        <div style="width:100%; height:220px;border:2px solid rgb(16,29,73);" id="Modalfrmmap">
                            <script>
                                initModalfrmmap();
                            </script>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
                <form id="EnterAddress">
                    <label style="color:red;">Hiii</label>
                </form>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    $('#LocateOnMap').hide();
                </script>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-md" style="margin:0;width: 75px;">Add</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-md" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="CancelModal()" style="font-weight: bold;">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have `<form></form>` under `<form></form>`, so removed that instead used `div`. By default assign `hidden` class to `LocateOnMap`. Then on `change` event of `radio` you can use jquery [toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) method to toggle visibility of `LocateOnMap` & `EnterAddress`.

```js
$("#modal-Frm").modal("show");


$('input[name=optradio]').change(function() {
  $("#EnterAddress,#LocateOnMap").toggleClass("hidden");
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal fade" id="modal-Frm">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm" style="width:480px;">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h3 class="modal-title">Add New Farmer</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form action="AddNewCustomer.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
              <label class="Modallabel">Address:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
              <label class="radio-inline"><input value="address" type="radio" name="optradio" checked>Enter Address</label>
              <label class="radio-inline"><input value="location" type="radio" name="optradio">Locate on Map</label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div>
            <div class="hidden" id="LocateOnMap">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                  <label class="Modallabel"></label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                  <div class="input-group input-group-sm" style="margin-top: -5px;margin-left: -15px;">
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                      <label class="Modallabel">Latitude:</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                      <div class="input-group input-group-sm" style="margin-top: -5px;">
                        <input id="Latitude" type="text" class="form-control ModalInput" name="Latitude" placeholder="Latitude" style="border-radius: 5px;" readonly>
                      </div><br>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                      <label class="Modallabel">Longitude:</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                      <div class="input-group input-group-sm" style="margin-top: -5px;">
                        <input id="Longitude" type="text" class="form-control ModalInput" name="Longitude" placeholder="Longitude" style="border-radius: 5px;" readonly>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div><br>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row" style="padding: 10px;">
                <div style="width:100%; height:220px;border:2px solid rgb(16,29,73);" id="Modalfrmmap">

                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="EnterAddress">

            <label style="color:red;">Hiii</label>
          </div>

        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-md" style="margin:0;width: 75px;">Add</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-md" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="CancelModal()" style="font-weight: bold;">Cancel</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

On **show.bs.modal** you can hide the form and set the radio button:

```
$('#modal-Frm').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
     $('[data-form-id="#EnterAddress"]').prop('checked', true).trigger('change');
})
```

I'd suggest to add a data attribute to each **name="optradio"** like:

```
data-form-id="#EnterAddress"
```

and for the second one:

```
data-form-id="#LocateOnMap"
```

In this way, on radio change you can switch between the two forms:

```
$('[name="optradio"]').on('change', function(e) {
     $('#modal-Frm').find('form[id]').hide();
     $(this.dataset.formId).show();
})
```

```js
$('#modal-Frm').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $('[data-form-id="#EnterAddress"]').prop('checked', true).trigger('change');
})
$('[name="optradio"]').on('change', function (e) {
    $('#modal-Frm').find('form[id]').hide();
    $(this.dataset.formId).show();
})


function CancelModal() {
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-Frm">
    Launch modal
</button>
<div class="modal fade" id="modal-Frm">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm" style="width:480px;">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h3 class="modal-title">Add New Farmer</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form action="AddNewCustomer.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <label class="Modallabel">Address:</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                            <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="optradio"
                                                               data-form-id="#EnterAddress">Enter Address</label>
                            <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="optradio" data-form-id="#LocateOnMap">Locate
                                on Map</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
                <form id="LocateOnMap">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <label class="Modallabel"></label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                            <div class="input-group input-group-sm" style="margin-top: -5px;margin-left: -15px;">
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <label class="Modallabel">Latitude:</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-8">
                                    <div class="input-group input-group-sm" style="margin-top: -5px;">
                                        <input id="Latitude" type="text" class="form-control ModalInput" name="Latitude"
                                               placeholder="Latitude" style="border-radius: 5px;" readonly>
                                    </div>
                                    <br>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <label class="Modallabel">Longitude:</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-8">
                                    <div class="input-group input-group-sm" style="margin-top: -5px;">
                                        <input id="Longitude" type="text" class="form-control ModalInput"
                                               name="Longitude" placeholder="Longitude" style="border-radius: 5px;"
                                               readonly>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <br>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row" style="padding: 10px;">
                        <div style="width:100%; height:220px;border:2px solid rgb(16,29,73);" id="Modalfrmmap">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
                <form id="EnterAddress">
                    <label style="color:red;">Hiii</label>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-md" style="margin:0;width: 75px;">Add
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-md" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="CancelModal()"
                        style="font-weight: bold;">Cancel
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form id="LocateOnMap" hidden>
```

this will make the form hidden on load

```
document.getElementById("LocateOnMap").style.display="block";
```

this is to display it